# Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr' in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

when output the Rmarkdown, there is an error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'.
the Rmarkdown code is very simple:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r}
print("hello")
```
````

I use the R version 3.4.4. Rstudio version 1.1.447

Comment: try running uninstalling and reinstalling knitr, and running update.packages

Comment: perhaps also restart your machine